# configmaps is forbidden: User "userid-codeklaudia" cannot create resource "configmaps" in API group "" at the cluster scope

Tags: openshift

I have been attempting to create a ConfigMap in the Openshift Developer Sandbox, but I am facing this difficulty :

[image: API group at the cluster scope]

[image: yaml_file]

Very obviously I don not seem to have permissions. But I did create other config maps before with no trouble. Additionally, I am in the Administrator mode of this console.

In case someone has a tip on that I would be ver grateful.

Comment: Are you sure you have the role "admin" for your project 
"userid-codeklaudia-dev"? Even though you can view the Administrator mode, do you have the role "cluster-admin"?